# Soap UI jenkins report

Tags: jenkins, report, soapui

I am trying to get a step by step soap tests report into jenkins. I have added the soapui testrunner in the jenkins command link, see below:

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat" -r -a -j -"C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\QA-soapui-project.xml"

I would like to know where does it save the junit report? I would like to publish the report in jenkins. I am adding the *.xml into the post build junit unit report but no luck with the report...

Comment: Why not use the SoapUI-Maven plugin? https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Summary Display Plugin` for publishing the test report, see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Summary+Display+Plugin.

The report will be stored in the workspace or in the execution directory.

Comment: Hi Archana, do you know where does the soap UI saves the xml file? so I can mention that in jenkins configuration. I am running the testrunner from jenkins